# Click the button print selected page(while click button send no of pages) in window.print()?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular7

while click button print the selected html page. Selected html have 5 pages but i want to print first two pages only. is it possible to send first two pages only while clicking the button .  window.print() is have any function to send print first 2 page only instead of 5 pages?

Comment: No. The `window.print` method does not take any parameters.. The only way I can see you doing it is to use `@media print` in CSS to hide the 3 remaining pages, then call the `window.print` method.

Comment: Here 2 is dynamically change at run time and also select 1-2 in printer pages properties while click button. my doubt is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

The Simple answer is **No**. Just because there is no parameter in `window.print()` method, or such a configuration to do so. See the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print). But there is a simple workaround for achieving the thing you want. What you can do is just set `style="max-height: 400px; overflow: hidden"` to the `body` of HTML just before calling `window.print()` method. Here in sample `400px` size is just for demo. You have to find that using `trial and error`. You also have to remove the `style` otherwise you won't be able to go through entire page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngx-print, which is an angular component that can be used to print parts of a page. - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-print

With ngx-print, you can use something like this :

```
<div id="sectionToPrint"> your content.. </div>
```

And then, for the print button, you can use ngx-print attribute like this :

```
<button printSectionId="sectionToPrint" ngxPrint> Print </button>
```

This will only print contents inside the "sectionToPrint" id.
Hope this helps.